# What may happen combining two power sources using a USB Y cable?

Tags: usb

There are USB Y cables. There shouldn't be but there are. Someone may connect the one end into another power source for whatever reason and that someone was unfortunately me not thinking about what I was doing.

This was to drive a power hungry audio interface of pro grade. I had this connected to an old computer for years with no issues (face value). Then I switched to a new computer and only realized after the interface hung that I still had that Y cable connected to another power source.

I know this isn't a good idea, but what specifically can happen and how likely is it to cause damage, not just a temporarily hung audio interface?

Some details: the USB bus had the higher voltage of 5.23v and the other power source is an original chromecast power supply with the lower voltage of 5.10v. Not sure about the current offered from it but between 500-1000mah. The USB bus is a USB3 port thus offering likely 900mah at most. This is enough for the interface so the extra power source is not needed now.

From what I can tell, the higher voltage source will "drive" the lower voltage source but does that mean the lower power source is the only one in danger? It still works and hasn't melted into a brick

From what I can remember I've NEVER ran this with only the extra power source powered, but the other way around has occurred (ie only the USB bus powered). From what I can understand, this primarily puts the extra power source at risk (the unpowered one)

I'd love some suggestions on how bad this is and what can actually happen and how likely that is. Still testing but so far everything seems OK. I've googled but only thing to be found is people saying it is bad, not so much how bad, what can happen and if someone actually fried something.

Comment: Some equipment is known to fry when 5V is applied into the USB ports (instead of out). IIRC that applies to some older mac books as an example. Devices breaks if the external power on 5V VBus keeps running when the Host (Mac) turns OFF. Note that these Y-cables violate USB spec.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, USB devices are allowed to draw 100mA without negotiation and can draw 500mA (or more depending on the source’s USB version) by negotiation.  However, Y cables typically assume that they can draw current without negotiation and share the current of up to 1A between two ports.  I guess it’s assumed that the host connectors are plugged into the same host or hub, so they are ultimately drawing from the same source and will share the current equally.  If you have different sources then anything could happen.  The most optimistic scenario is that the source with the greater current capability will supply most/all of the current, but the pessimistic scenarios are bad to varying degrees.

Comment: Yeah, it's obviously not a great idea. It's just so hard to find specifics on what issues could be expected. I haven't downright fried anything, as all devices still work, but I don't know what to look for in terms of more subtle issues potentially caused by this.

Comment: It’s difficult to say exactly without knowing the internal workings of the two sources.  You can imagine that if one has a slightly higher voltage than the other then a potentially large current could flow.  The lower voltage source may not be designed to accept an incoming current and so it’s behaviour can’t be predicted.

Comment: Yeah, there's a 0,13V difference between the sources. The lower voltage source seems to still be ok, it functions correctly from all I can tell. Hopefully, it had sufficient protection. It's an official Chromecast power supply. One can only hope Google doesn't use "china crap" ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with USB Y cables is, like you said, it allows you to connect two power supplies together.

That should never be done, at least not without any precaution anyway.

So basically, it's the same as using a fully wired USB-A to USB-A plugs connecting two compurers or power supplies together.

It will likely do anything to the USB audio interface, as it just draws power. It could have fried your new computer, maybe only USB interface damage with a blown fuse or so much damage it's beyond repair. I guess if the USB power supply had been damaged, it would have been irrelevant.

When your computer is turned off, the external supply will try to push power in to the computer through the USB port on the motherboard.

Same for the case if PC is on and external supply is off.

And when both are on, the voltages are not same so either one does nothing and the other does all the work, or one tries to push voltage higher while the other tries to pull voltage lower, and current flows between power supplies.

Well, what could happen is nothing if both devices have some protection what happens if two supplies are shorted together.

One possibility is that the power supply tries to feed power up your PC via USB when PC is off. It can damage the motherboard or PC power supply if they can't handle that. On the other hand the USB power supply can be overloaded by too much load and it can damage. Usually they have overload protection and shut down, but that means it might try restarting and shutting down 100 times per second.

So anything could happen, as devices may not handle scenarios that should never happen. A properly designed device would take it into account and handle it, but as designing protection and adding protection components cost money, not all cheap devices bother to implement any.

So, don't use cables that should not exist. Or only use them in short term and according to instructions. It is too easy to forget and cause damage to expensive equipment. Sometimes I am amazed what people buy and plug into their expensive computers without any hesitation. Like some MCU boards that are so badly designed that should never be plugged into any computer.

Comment: Yeah I'd never consider that cable again. It was one of those quick fixes in the moment when things were connected to an old computer I didn't care about. Then the darn thing was forgotten under a desk and hooked up to a new computer and I had a chill through the spine realising it still being there.

Thankfully, I haven't downright fried anything. All devices still function and I can't notice any immediate and obvious issues. What I worry about is what sporadic or situational issues this could have caused that I do not know about yet. I'm not sure what to test other than general function.